# Problems accessing databases on remote postgresql sever

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a postgresql (9.1.4) server running on a remote machine (Ubuntu 12.04), and I'm having trouble accessing it on my local machine. Specifically, on my local machine, I can access the remote server using only the username "postgres" and the database name "postgres", even though I have other user names and databases. First some of the background information. While in the interactive environment invoked with "psql" on the remote machine, I created another user, called "mxtxdb", and set the password for that user. I also created a database called "mxtxdb". To demonstrate their existence, I logged onto the remote machine and ran:

```
sudo su postgres
Password:
postgres@myhost:~$ psql                                  
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 mxtxdb    |                                                | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mxtxdb    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | mxtxdb=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Furthermore, while still on the remote machine, I can access the database from the "mxtxdb" postgresql account:

```
postgres@myhost:~$ psql -h localhost -U mxtxdb -d mxtxdb
Password for user mxtxdb: 
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

mxtxdb=>
```

But when I try to do the same on the local machine, I get this:

```
psql -h <server's address> -U postgres -d "postgres" -p 5432
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

and

```
psql -h <server's address> -U "postgres" -d "mxtxdb" -p 5432
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  database "mxtxdb" does not exist
```

and

```
psql -h <server's address> -U "mxtxdb" -d "mxtxdb" -p 5432
Password for user mxtxdb: 
psql: FATAL:  role "mxtxdb" does not exist
```

The last two lines of my pg_hba.conf file are:

```
host    all             mxtxdb          0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             postgres        0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

and the listen_addresses is set to '*' (and uncommented) in the postgresql.conf file.

Any idea why I cannot access other accounts or databases remotely, but I can when ssh'd into the remote machine?

Comment: +1 Complete, good detailed question. Thankyou. No immediate ideas, though.

Comment: Fairly wild idea, but: Are there any rules in the iptables `nat` table that might be redirecting traffic? `iptables -t nat -L -n` .

Comment: Also, what happens if you ssh to the problem server and connect locally using psql, but instead of using `localhost` use the public IP `<server's address>` ? Additionally: try `tcptraceroute <server's address>` from the client you're having issues with.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! Here's what happens when I run `iptables -t nat -L -n`:

`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

My system doesn't have tcptraceroute installed, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: tcptraceroute returned in 25 hops with: `25  <server> (<IP address>) [open]  98.399 ms  95.556 ms  98.614 ms`

Comment: 25 hops? So this server is quite a long way away from the client , not just on the same LAN? What about `tcptraceroute <serverip> 5432`, tracing where traffic to PostgreSQL's actual port goes? Please also show results from `psql -h <serverip> -U "mxtxdb" -d "mxtxdb"` when run on the server; ie just substitute <serverip> for localhost.

Comment: BTW, most of these issues end up being "I'm connecting to a different database than I thought I was".

Comment: Yes, I'm running PostgreSQL on an Amazon EC2 server instance, although I don't think that's a problem, because all of the required ports are open, and I'm able to reach the server to access other services like SSH. Also, the above command returning in 25 hops was actually `tcptraceroute <serverip> 5432`, it didn't return at all without the port at the end of the command. Finally, when I run `psql -h <serverip> -U "mxtxdb" -d "mxtxdb"` from the remote server itself, I get `psql: FATAL:  role "mxtxdb" does not exist`, which is interesting.

Comment: I'm with Craig - this usually means you're connecting to somewhere different. Connect as postgres and try \l to list database and \du for users.

Comment: You're absolutely right! When I connect remotely as "postgres", then I can only see user "postgres" and database "postgres". Does this indicate that the server is communicating with a different database directory than the psql invocations running locally on the remote server are? Is there a command that I can run inside psql to show the path of the underlying database directory because perhaps they are not pointing to the same directory? Or maybe it's a permissions issue wherein the other databases and users are not properly exposed to remote connections?

Comment: I've now noticed that I have pg_hba.conf and postgesql.conf files in both the /usr/local/pgsql/data and also in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main directories, so maybe I improperly initialized the database cluster during the installation process.

Comment: @Max If you're on Ubuntu (which uses `pg_wrapper`) but did a manual `initdb` instead of using the `pg_initcluster` command, that could well be the case.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to Craig Richard for your suggestions, and in fact you were both correct. Here's what happened: I installed PostgreSQL using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1`, and then I followed the instructions for configuring the server at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime.html . Unfortunately, what I did not notice was that the apt-get install process creates a postgresql database cluster by default, so when I followed the instructions to create a new one, I then had two clusters, one at /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main and one at /usr/local/pgsql/data, and I was interacting with different clusters when I logged in locally vs remotely. When I removed the second cluster, the issue was resolved and I was able to connect remotely.

My takeaways from this process: when installing postgresql with apt-get, and then following the instructions in the postgresql manual, be aware that the install process will create a postgres operating system user by default, and will also create a database cluster by default, so those steps in the manual do not need to be performed. If anyone experiences an error like:

```
"FATAL: role/database '<name>' does not exist"
```

when you are sure you've created that user or database, check to ensure that you're operating with the correct database cluster.

Thanks again!